# Turning randomized BPP algorithm to stronger statement with polynomial time

Tags: probability, computational-complexity, random, random-functions

Having difficulty with a homework problem, so just looking for some guidance.

For a function $f(x)$ in BPP defined on strings x in $\Sigma^{*}$, we know there is a constant c > 0 and a randomized algorithm A(x, R) with running time bounded by $|x|^{c}$ with the following property: For each x let R be a random string of length $|x|^c$, then $P( A(x, R) \neq f (x)) < 1/3$.

Show that there is also a polynomial algorithm $B(x, R)$ that uses the same
common random bit sequence R for all strings x of the same length:
$$P\{\exists x \in \Sigma^{n} B(x, R) \neq f (x)\} < \frac{1}{3}. $$

In other words, show the probability that there is a string x of length n where $B(x, R) \neq f(x) < \frac{1}{3}$.
We're given a hint: First drive down the failure probability to exponentially small, using repetition,
then apply the union bound.

I understand how to reduce the failure probability to be insignificant with repetition, as this is a BPP problem. However, I'm not sure where or how I'd apply the union bound.

Comment: Could you say what "BPP" means ?

Comment: bounded-error probabilistic polynomial time

Answer (score 0):

(hints only)

Any "$\exists$" corresponds to a union. The event "$\exists x(\text{x is bad})$" is the union over $x$ of the events "$\text{x is bad}$". The relevant union bound is therefore

$$\mathbb{P}[\exists x\in\Sigma^n \cdot (B(x,R)\neq f(x))]\leq \sum_{x\in\Sigma^n}\mathbb{P}[B(x,R)\neq f(x)]$$

You need to bound this. It might be useful to first bound it by $|\Sigma|^n \cdot \max_{x\in\Sigma^n}\mathbb{P}[B(x,R)\neq f(x)].$

Comment: How would I go about finding $P[B(x, R) \neq f(x)]$? I thought we reduced the probability of failure of $B(x, R)$ to be insignificant.

Comment: @bag531: the point is to make "insignificant" rigorous - exactly how small does it need to be? Well, you want to make it small enough that when you multiply by $|\Sigma|^n,$ you get something less than $1/3.$